# running Install.ps1 everytime with Nuget package update

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

I have a small question

**Does Install.ps1 file runs every time when we update the already installed Nuget package or if we install the same package over an installed project?**

**If it doesn't is thare any way that we can run our power shell script every time after the package is updated or installed for the first time?**

Thanks

regards

Comment: How is this question fundamentally different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785002/nuget-powershell-script-install-ps1?

Comment: Well that question is about how to change the script and here i am asking about the abstract steps :) But yes the question is almost the same.